# Deleting of DSpace Collection fails

Tags: dspace

As Administrator in DSpace 5.3 I try to remove (delete) a collection that is not needed anymore, but I get the message:

ERROR: update or delete on table "item" violates foreign key constraint "workspaceitem_item_id_fkey" on table "workspaceitem" Detail: Key (item_id)=(70) is still referenced from table "workspaceitem".

The collection does not contain any archived document.

And although I added myself to all the workflow-steps and made me also Collection-adminstrator of this collection, I don't see any submitted item.

Is there another possibility to remove a collection?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to the fact one (or more) item(s) is (are) being submitted in the collection you're trying to delete.

To check that, you can run the following PSQL query:

```
select workspace_item_id, item.item_id, submitter_id, handle from workspaceitem, item, handle where workspaceitem.item_id = item.item_id and handle.resource_type_id = '3' and handle.resource_id = workspaceitem.collection_id;
```

If the "handle" column corresponds to the handle of the collection you're trying to delete, check the submitter ID for that item. If the login as feature is enabled, you can login as that user (their IDs are listed in the "People" admin menu together with their names and emails), go to his / her submissions page, and cancel the submission. If not, you may have to contact that user to do it himself / herself.

If none of these approaches are possible, I assume it would be possible to delete the item directly from the database, but I would advise you against that approach (or at least make sure that you also remove all dependencies from all tables in the database).

Cheers,
Benoît